# Fatal Exception: Main on FragmentManager Transaction during .commit()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm adding an OnClickListener into a programatically created layout (works fine). The Listener should open up a fragment containing a List of options. However, the following Error is raised during the line `transaction.commit();`

Error:

> 2019-12-12 10:15:02.382 5365-5365/com.example.plabsprojects.mtglifecounter_league E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.plabsprojects.mtglifecounter_league, PID: 5365
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2114)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
>           at com.example.plabsprojects.mtglifecounter_league.MatchActivity.setClicklistener_ChangePlayerName(MatchActivity.java:73)
>           at com.example.plabsprojects.mtglifecounter_league.PlayerView$3.onClick(PlayerView.java:227)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
>           at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25881)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)

Using a `catch` statement, the error message states:

> 2019-12-12 11:45:36.552
>   7903-7903/com.example.plabsprojects.mtglifecounter_league D/Debugging:
>   Error: Activity has been destroyed

This is the function implemented by the OnClickListener (in class MatchActivity):

```
public void setClicklistener_ChangePlayerName(View view){
    DialogFragment dialogFragment;
    dialogFragment = new ChangePlayerNameFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(dialogFragment, "MeinDialog");
    transaction.commit(); // The error occurrs on this line
}
```

The actual OnClickListener function (in class PlayerView):

```
private OnClickListener changePlayerName= new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        MatchActivity matchActivity = new MatchActivity();
        matchActivity.setClicklistener_ChangePlayerName(view);
    }
};
```

This is the fragment, that should be called:

```
public class ChangePlayerNameFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle b) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.match_change_player_Name_header));
        final String[] names = new String[]{"Pascal", "Christopher", "Max", "Axel"};
        builder.setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                //Close Dialogue
                dialog.dismiss();

                //What to do with the Item
                ((MatchActivity) getActivity()).ShowSelectedPlayerName(names[i]);

            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        return dialog;
    }

}
```

What am I missing here? Or how do I research other possible reasons for this issue? The code is, as far as I can tell, correct. No build errors whatsoever.

Comment: Just that one line in crash logs ?

Comment: No, there are more. Posted above.

Comment: What is this line `new MatchActivity();` you must never initialize `Activity` using `new`

Comment: `MatchActivity matchActivity = new MatchActivity();` – You cannot do that. The system must handle `Activity` instantiation. Why are you doing that from `PlayerView`? That is, why do you think you need to create a new `MatchActivity` there? What is `PlayerView`, exactly, and where is it being used?

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA: This line is from the class ´PlayerView`. The class itself is not an activity, but is populating the actual activity `MatchActivity` with the layout. The function, which is called through this object is located in the activity class. Hope, that clears it up. Otherwise: How do I handle that?

Comment: @MikeM.: There are two classes: `MatchActivity`, which is the actual activity and `PlayerView`, which is a supportive class, that contains all code for the needed layout in the activity. I need the `OnClicklistener` in `PlayerView` as the respective objects are created there. I needed that structure, because Fragments need `extend AppCompatActivity` and `PlayerView` already extends `View`

Comment: If `PlayerView` is a `View` inside `MatchActivity`, why not just set an `OnClickListener` on `PlayerView` in `MatchActivity`, and have it do the `FragmentTransaction` there?

Comment: @MikeM. The `FragmentTransaction` is already in `MatchActivity`. I tried moving the `OnClickListener`, but the error is still there.

Comment: "The `FragmentTransaction` is already in `MatchActivity`." – Yes, I know that. I meant, call the transaction code from the `OnClickListener` set on `PlayerView`. "I tried moving the `OnClickListener`, but the error is still there." – Then you're likely still making the same mistake. I meant, for example, in `MatchActivity`, something like `PlayerView playerView = ...;`, `playerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { setClicklistener_ChangePlayerName(v); } });`. No `new MatchActivity()` necessary, 'cause you're already in `MatchActivity`.

Comment: @MikeM.: Thanks for the input! I'll try that later. I checked the `transaction` variable now with a catch. Error message updated above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean for that to do. It's the same error. Catching it won't fix the underlying issue; just might prevent an outright crash, is all.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the suggestion! That was somehow the problem. I did, what you explained previously, thanks!